# Custom Sort Using 4 Columns

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort data by four different columns, first D, then E, then F, then G, in ascending value. The number of rows will change each time I run the report so I need it to sort whatever is active in the worksheet. This VBA code is working, but I suspect it wouldn't if there were more than 30533 rows.

```
Sub Rx_Custom_Sort_1()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
:=Range("D2:D30533"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
:=Range("E2:E30533"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
:=Range("F2:F30533"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
:=Range("G2:G30533"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b").Sort
.SetRange Range("A1:N30533")
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sort by Multiple Columns**

- If the sheet is in the workbook containing this code, replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook`.

**Basic**

```vb
Sub RxCustomSort1()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b")
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Sort
            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add rg.Columns("D")
                .Add rg.Columns("E")
                .Add rg.Columns("F")
                .Add rg.Columns("G")
            End With
            .SetRange rg
            .Header = xlYes
            .Apply
            .SortFields.Clear
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Range (Even More Basic)**

- Note the opposite order.

```vb
Sub RxCustomSortRange()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b")
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .Sort .Columns("G"), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
            .Sort .Columns("F"), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
            .Sort .Columns("E"), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
            .Sort .Columns("D"), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
        End With
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

**Docs**

- To dig in deeper, study the following which will also clarify why in the screenshot, the arrow in the first column didn't disappear after the sort (`.AutoFilter`).

  - [Sort Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sort)
  - [SortFields Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields)
  - [SortFields.Add2 Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add2)
  - [SortField Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfield)
  - [Range.Sort Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort)
  - [Worksheet.Sort Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.sort)
  - [AutoFilter.Sort Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter.sort)

**Study**

- Reference each object to study its methods and properties via the Intellisense.

```vb
Sub RxCustomSortIntelliSense()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b")
    With ws ' Worksheet Object
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' Range Object
        Dim so As Sort: Set so = .Sort
        With so ' Sort Object
            Dim sfs As SortFields: Set sfs = .SortFields
            With sfs ' SortFields Object
                .Clear
                Dim sf As SortField: Set sf = .Add(rg.Columns("D"), _
                    xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal)
                With sf ' SortField Object (no apparent use here)
                    Debug.Print .Key.Address
                    Debug.Print .SortOn
                    Debug.Print .Order
                    Debug.Print .CustomOrder
                    Debug.Print .DataOption
                    Debug.Print .Parent.Count ' SortFields
                    Debug.Print .Parent.Parent.SortFields.Count ' Sort
                    Debug.Print .Parent.Parent.Parent.Name ' Worksheet
                    Debug.Print .Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name ' Workbook
                    Debug.Print .Priority
                    '.Delete
                    '.ModifyKey()
                    '.SetIcon()
                End With
                .Add rg.Columns("E"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal
                .Add rg.Columns("F"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal
                .Add rg.Columns("G"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal
            End With
            .SetRange rg
            .Header = xlYes
            .Apply
            sfs.Clear
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! (The first one you sent - "Basic.") Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to use this same code (the "Basic" version), but this time I want to sort two rows A to Z and one Z to A, so for example column  A A-Z, Column B A-Z, and then Column C Z-A. Do you know how I would change the code to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be `.Add rg.Columns("C"), , xlDescending` short for `.Add Key:=rg.Columns("C"), Order:=xlDescending`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. So appreciative as I am literally learning all of this as I go through recording macros, youtube, and this site. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Assumes Col A can be used to determine the size of source table.
- Get the last data row# of the table by `End(xlUp)`.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Sub Rx_Custom_Sort_1()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Prescriptions_Clean_2b")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Sort.SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add2 Key:=.Range("D2:D" & lastRow), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=.Range("E2:E" & lastRow), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=.Range("F2:F" & lastRow), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=.Range("G2:G" & lastRow), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        With .Sort
            .SetRange .Parent.Range("A1:N" & lastRow)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This one is giving me an error message: Run-time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Which line throws error?