# VBA - Sort Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am currently use sort but for only 1 column

```
   Sheets("BP").Range("A1:Q3000").Sort Key1:=Sheets("BP").Range("K1"), _
   Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
   Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal,
```

How could I add another column on to here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the Microsoft VBA documentation [Range.Sort method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) you can add three key parameters for ordering within the Sort method. If you need more help could you provide a data sample and the expected output

Comment: Please have a look onto the _key2_ and _Order2_ parameters of Sort method

Comment: Place the cursor on the word `Sort` in your code and press `F1`

Comment: Have a look at [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78014517) to *"Custom Sort Using 4 Columns"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said suggested by @[Shrotter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17172829/shrotter) you should use `Key2` and `Order2` parameters :

```
Sheets("BP").Range("A1:Q3000").Sort Key1:=Sheets("BP").Range("K1"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:=Sheets("BP").Range("L1"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal
```

`Key2` is set to `Sheets("BP").Range("L1")`, assuming you want to sort by column `L` after sorting by column `K`. Both are set to `xlAscending` for ascending order. If you want to sort in an other way you can use for example : `xlDescending`